# Problems using ng-class to switch a class on ng-click function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Could somebody please tell me where this is going wrong? I basically have a simple check of a value - if the value is true, it should set the class to headerOn. If false, it should be headerOff. Easy. Here's the code:

```
<div ng-class="headerCheck ? 'headerOn' : 'headerOff'">
```

And the function that I hit:

```
$scope.headerControl = function() {

    $scope.headerCheck = true;

    console.log($scope.headerCheck);
}
```

I can confirm that the log is true. Any ideas why this isn't working for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the syntax here.

The correct approach would be these:

`<div class="{{headerCheck ? 'headerOn' : 'headerOff'}}">`

or

```
<div ng-class="{'headerOn': headerCheck, 'headerOff' : !headerCheck }">
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for `ng-class` is wrong, it should be:

```
ng-class="{'headerOn' : headerCheck, 'headerOff' : !headerCheck}"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is correct, but you are not telling angularjs that it needs to evaluate what is in the `""` as an angular expression.  As Karthik stated, you could change the div to

```
<div ng-class="{headerCheck ? 'headerOn' : 'headerOff'}">
```

which then makes `headerCheck ? 'headerOn' : 'headerOff'` an angularjs expression.

**EDIT:**

Since you did not give a chunk of your code and only gave you snippet, you may want to make sure that the div you referenced in your question is being controlled by the same controller that has your `$scope.headerControl` function included in.